# Поиск похожих предложений в бд

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование

Всем доброго времени суток. Имею 2 таблицы(в скоре их будет очень много) в которой постоянно изменяются значения, кроме столбца teams и sport, мне нужно вывести все записи тб1 и тб2 с одинаковыми матчами, тоесть вывести тб1-команда1 -- тб2-команда1 и тут возникает проблема, в разных таблицах столбец teams постоянно отличается,
 Например: таблица 1 (Чехия - Венгрия), таблица 2 (Матч с чехия против венгрии),
 или таблица 1 (Бовар. - Чехословакия), таблица 2 (Бовария против Чехословакии).

Нужно как то сравнивать строки и находить самые похожие, в какую сторону смотреть ?

Comment: примеры таблиц и данных приведите, а также пример SQL запроса, который у вас не получается.

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону полнотекстового поиска (оператор MATCH). или даже внешного, вроде sphinx. А вообще не дело хранить в БД данные в свободной форме, БД не предназначены для этого. Лучим решением было бы реализовать механизмы поиска соответствия в скрипте, который добавляет данные в таблицы. Что бы в таблицы сажать уже формализованные данные. Для поддержки этого механизма можно было бы какие нибудь шаблоны сделать и хранить в БД. И еще сильно настораживает "_вскоре их будет очень много_". БД неправильно спроектирована, если во время ее работы появляются новые таблицы

Comment: я парсю данные с сайтов и заношу в бд чтобы потом смотреть одинаковые команды с разных сайтов,

Comment: Ну тогда это как раз задача парсера найти соответствия ID команд или игроков из общих справочников. потому что именно парсер знает с каким он сайтом работает и на что больше похоже то, что он от туда получает. И вот "команда из таблицы 2" опять же настораживает. Обычно в БД должна быть одна таблица "команды"  и в ней они хранятся с какими то дополнительными атрибутами, показывающими к чему они относятся. например какой нибудь id сайта с которого она взята или еще что то в этом роде. В общем структура должна быть такова, что бы таблицы создались только в время разработки, но не работы приложени

Comment: как мне узнать что на сайте 1 и 2 есть одинаковые команды,  у всех сайтов одинаково только поле teams вот его я и пытаюсь найти со всех сайтов

Comment: Не ужели он в пределах одного сайта сильно отличается, там нет какого фиксированного формата вывода, по которому можно было бы конкретно для этого сайта хотя бы разделить строку на 2 части, кто с кем играет и выделить дополнительную информацию. после этого можно было бы сделать справочники названий в которых фиксировать как та или иная команда называется на каких нибудь сайтах. или например ключевые слова (вплоть до регулярок) по которым можно понять что есть что

Comment: Вот надпись например "Матч с чехия против венгрии" на том сайте всегда пишется слово "матч" и слово "против" ? Если да, то это как раз забота парсера убрать эти слова и загрузить в отдельные колонки как минимум "чехия" "венгрия", а лучше найти соответствия в справочниках и записать сразу ID и выдать куда то отдельно то что не распознается, что бы человек мог глянуть, определить и на будущее правило написать

Comment: Mike, мысль понял, только вот насчет справочников не очень, можешь пример привести

Comment: Скажем есть команда Бовария с ID=1, к ней в отдельной таблице пишем как обычно она еще называется т.е. пишем туда 1, "Бовар", можно дополнительно еще поле что это для сайта такого то (хотя возможно это излишне). Или даже запись вроде 1,"Бовар%" что бы обычный like мог найти по такой маске.  Для Чехии-Чехословакии так же синонимы задавать.